# Is it possible to POST an item with Geolocation Column on SharePoint through MS Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an Item on SharePoint through Graph APIs.

Contextually, I have to set the coordinates of a `geolocation` column.

I tried several payload requests, including the one below, but I always get `400 - Bad Request` as a response.

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Title": "test",
        "myGeolocationColumn@odata.type": "graph.location",
        "myGeolocationColumn": {
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 19,
                "longitude": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the documentation, but I cannot find anything useful.

Can you please provide an example? But, above all, is it possible to set a `geolocation` column with MS Graph APIs?

Comment: It seems not supported. I've tried to add location value from UI and then call `/sites/{siteid/lists/{listid}/items?$expand=fields` to check the json object for location column. If I use the same json object in  `POST /sites/{siteid/lists/{listid}/items` I always get `400 - Bad Request`. No chance to add location value from Graph API